# HTML tags showing in output of hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array containing strings and some elements include href tags for hyperlinks. The array is as follows:

```
var yesResources2 = ["",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "Refer to <a href='https://www.ipc.on.ca/wp-
    content/uploads/Resources/naid.pdf'>Best Practices for Secure 
    Destruction of Sensitive Information</a>",
    "",
    "",
    'Refer to <a href="https://www.bdc.ca/en/articles-
    tools/technology/invest-technology/pages/computer-security-how-protect-
    your-technology.aspx">Business Development Bank of Canada’s “10 
    questions to boost your tech security”</a>',
   'Refer to <a href="https://www.bdc.ca/en/articles-
    tools/technology/invest-technology/pages/computer-security-how-protect-
    your-technology.aspx">Business Development Bank of Canada’s “10 
    questions to boost your tech security”</a>',
    "",
    ""]
```

I have written a function in JS to display certain elements of the array. The function is working fine, but the output is not coming out as a hyperlink but rather as follows:

```
Refer to <a href="https://www.bdc.ca/en/articles-tools/technology/invest-
technology/pages/computer-security-how-protect-
your-technology.aspx">Business Development Bank of Canada’s “10 
questions to boost your tech security</a>
```

Why is this happening? It was displaying as hyperlinks in an earlier stage of the project I'm working on...

The functions that involved in displaying the links as follows:

**Function to determine which element to display**

```
function current()
  {
      if(selection === 0 && yesResources2[questionsCounter] != "")
      {
        return yesResources2[questionsCounter];
      }
      else if(selection === 1 && noResources2[questionsCounter] != "")
      {
      return noResources2[questionsCounter];
      }
      else
      {
         return 'You are on the right track!';
      }
  };
```

**Code to display**

```
document.getElementById("modalContent").textContent = callback();
```

where `callback()` is given as `current()` to another function

Comment: Use `.innerHTML = /* ... */` instead of `.textContent = /* ... */`.

Comment: Btw, please note that if in any way the content of the arrays come from user input, that code will be open to xss attacks if you make it interpret the strings as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding it as a *text* - you should be adding it as *html* like this:

```
document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = callback()
```

Simplified demo below:

```js
var yesResources2 = ["",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "Refer to <a href='https://www.ipc.on.ca/wp-content / uploads / Resources / naid.pdf '>Best Practices for Secure Destruction of Sensitive Information </a>",
  "",
  "",
  'Refer to <a href="https://www.bdc.ca/en/articles-tools / technology / invest - technology / pages / computer - security - how - protect -your - technology.aspx ">Business Development Bank of Canada’s “10 questions to boost your tech security” </a>','Refer to <a href="https://www.bdc.ca/en/articles-tools / technology / invest - technology / pages / computer - security - how - protect -your - technology.aspx ">Business Development Bank of Canada’s “10 questions to boost your tech security” </a>',
  "",
  ""
]

selection = 0;
questionsCounter = 7;

function current() {
  if (selection === 0 && yesResources2[questionsCounter] != "") {
    return yesResources2[questionsCounter];
  } else if (selection === 1 && noResources2[questionsCounter] != "") {
    return noResources2[questionsCounter];
  } else {
    return 'You are on the right track!';
  }
};

document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = current();
```

```html
<div id="modalContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("modalContent").textContent = callback();
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`textContent` will add a text node to the element. so if you check the rendered `<a>`, it'll show `&lt;a&gt;` because it is added after encoding.

To avoid this, use `innerHTML`;

The code will be

```
document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = callback();
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simplest solution would be to use the yesResources2 elements as you've defined it, but use

```
document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = callback();
```

However, I think the above is prone to typos and malformed html in your raw string. The following method would be more robust, and possibly more secure as well.

---

In your array you can store a few separate pieces of information for each item. Something like:

```
var yesResources2 = [
    {
        outerText: 'Refer to ',
        href: 'https://www.ipc.on.ca/wp-
content/uploads/Resources/naid.pdf',
        innerText: 'Best Practices for Secure 
Destruction of Sensitive Information'
    },
    { 
        /* etc */
    }
]
```

then:

```
function current() {
    if(selection === 0 && yesResources2[questionsCounter].innerText != undefined)
    {
        return yesResources2[questionsCounter];
    } 
    /* etc */
}
```

...

```
var modalContent = document.getElementById('modalContent');
var resource = callback();

// If there is text to be displayed before the link, create a
// textNode to hold it, and append it to the modal's body
if (resource.outerText && resource.outerText != "") {
    var outerTextNode = document.createTextNode(resource.outerText);
    modalContent.appendChildNode(outerTextNode);
}

// If there is a link to be displayed, create an anchor element,
// set the href attribute appropriately, and append it to the modal.
if (resource.href && resource.href != "") {
    var anchorNode = document.createElement('A');
    anchorNode.setAttribute('href', resource.href);

    // Add the text for the link
    if (resource.innerText) {
        anchorNode.appendChildNode(document.createTextNode(resource.innerText);
    }
    modalContent.appendChildNode(anchorNode)
}
```